# Realtime Sharing of Pointer/Cursor of Each Player in Game Room Using PUN2/MRTK2 on Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, photon, windows-mixed-reality

Is there a way to share each player's raycast pointer/cursor with the other players in realtime?  I'm using PUN2 and MRTK2 and Hololens 2.

Approaches I've tried so far:

1. I tried a naïve approach of modifying the MRTK provided `ShellHandRayPointer` to contain a PhotonView and then using that on the `MixedRealityToolkit` object within the scene, but that seems to have no effect.
2. I've tried creating a cursor prefab based off of MRTK's `CursorFocus` in which I add a `Surface Magnetism` component (tracking the hands) and then instantiate this prefab for each player in PUN2's `OnJoinedRoom` callback.  After the instantiation call, I add the object to a non-rendered layer for the player with the goal of hiding it for the local player but allowing it show up for other players.  This seems to hide the object as expected when only one player is in the room, but when a second player joins, the first player then sees a cursor show up that tracks with their hand movement, which seems unexpected to me (of note is that I'm using one Hololens 2 headset with a computer acting as the second player).  Though perhaps this "crossed" behavior is due to the `Surface Magnetism` component?

Thanks!

Step-by-step images of how I modified the `ShellHandRayPointer` with a PhotonView and then reattached to the MRTK system:

scene:
[image: scene]

MRTK system:
[image: MRTK system part 1]

MRTK system part 2: reference to cloned `ShellHandRayPointer`:
[image: MRTK system part 2: reference to cloned ShellHandRayPointer]

my cloned `ShellHandRayPointer` part 1:
[image: my cloned ShellHandRayPointer part 1]

PhotonView components expanded on the cloned `ShellHandRayPointer`:
[image: PhotonView components expanded on the cloned ShellHandRayPointer]

Comment: Do you refer to the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-01 to achieve multi-user sharing? ShellHandRayPointer is controlled by the Input system, you may need a custom prefab or simply clone and place it manually.

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT could you elaborate more on each of those options?  I've tried cloning the prefab and adding a PhotonView and then tying this to the MRTK  system but that didn't have any effect that I'm aware of.  I'm not clear on how to place it manually or if your suggestion of creating a custom prefab is any different than what I just explained.

Comment: Would you share more details about how do you modified the ShellHandRayPointer? I am not clear about the 2nd question. Are you creating a cursor that only shows to other players? Step-by-step actions or screenshots may help.

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT See my updated question for images of how I modified the `ShellHandRayPointer` and tried to attach it to MRTK within the scene.  My expectation was that each player's ray/cursor would be viewable by every other player within the same game room.  Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will dig into it and try to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding how to share objects in Photon in real time, as far as I know, the real-time shared objects in Photon need to be instantiated by **PhotonNetwork.Instantiate**, but **ShellHandRayPointer** in MRTK is instantiated by Input system.

You can customize a copy of **ShellHandRayPointer**, map the position and rotation of **ShellHandRayPointer** to the copy at runtime and share this copy in Photon in real time.

The position and rotation of **ShellHandRayPointer** can be obtained in **MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem.DetectedInputSources**. Or you can use Unity's methods to get this Game Object directly.

For the cursor, you can use the same method above to create a copy of the cursor and map its position and rotation.